# popd not letting open excel in script

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

```
@echo off

set data_sheet="\\EXAMPLE\module1\Automation\Datasheets\ZXC"
set csv_name=%3

pushd "%data_sheet%\%1\%2"
start excel "%cd%\%csv_name%"

REM need to put condition, until excel is open, dont popd
popd
```

Created above script to open a excel from a remote path.
excel not opening after running this script

```
$ data folder subfolder test.xls
```

Here, if I comment out popd it works fine. But commenting out popd causes many virtual drives opened if i run this multiple times.

Is there a way to put condition where I open excel, do my stuff and when I close it? popd should occur (like in a conditional way).

Error after running script to open excel:

[image: error after running script to open excel]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `start /wait`. Or don't use `pushd` in the first place – Excel supports UNC paths (as do almost all apps *except* for Cmd):

```
set data_sheet="\\EXAMPLE\module1\Automation\Datasheets\ZXC"
set csv_name=%3

start excel "%data_sheet%\%1\%2\%csv_name%"
```

If you need a fixed mapping, create it using `net use`.

Comment: It fails as "data_sheet" path as a space in the address               .
for example there is space between module and one here: set data_sheet="\\EXAMPLE\module one\Automation\Datasheets\ZXC"

it just says, cannot open EXAMPLE\module.xls